# Induction troubles proving a formula.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having a tough time proving the following formula. Suppose $a,b\in R$ a ring. Define $a^{(0)}=a$, $a^{(1)}=[a,b]\equiv ab-ba$, and then $a^{(k)}=[a^{(k-1)},b]$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k b^iab^{k-i}=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+1}{j+1}b^{k-j}a^{(j)}.
$$

I wanted to do this with induction on $k$, but the presence of $k$ in each term of the sum is making it difficult to get the right form of things. I had something like
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+2}{j+1}b^{k+1-j}a^{(j)} &=
\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k+2}{j+1}b^{k+1-j}a^{(j)}+a^{(k+1)}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^k\left[\binom{k+1}{j}+\binom{k+1}{j+1}\right]b^{k+1-j}a^{(j)}+a^{(k+1)}\\
&=b\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+1}{j}b^{k-j}a^{(j)}+b\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+1}{j+1}b^{k-j}a^{(j)}+a^{(k+1)}\\
&=b\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+1}{j}b^{k-j}a^{(j)}+b\sum_{i=0}^k b^iab^{k-i}+a^{(k+1)}
\end{align*}
$$
but this is still far from what I want. I tried doing induction in the other direction, but had similar problems. I don't see how the recursive definition of $a^{(k)}$ comes into play. How can the formula be properly derived? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the LHS terms as

$$S_k=\sum_{i=0}^k b^i a b^{k-i}.$$

Notice this satisfies the recurrence

$$S_{k+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} b^i a b^{k+1-i}=\left(\sum_{i=0}^k b^iab^{k+1-i}\right)+b^{k+1}ab^{k+1-(k+1)}=S_kb+b^{k+1}a.$$

If you establish that $S_k$ and the RHS are equal as a base case, we need only prove that the RHS *also* satisfies this recurrence so they are the same sequence (as the recurrence solution is unique).

It helps to first note that $a^{(k)}b=ba^{(k)}+a^{(k+1)}$ using the inductive definition.

Now take the RHS of the desired claim, right-multiply by $b$ and add $b^{k+1}a$: from there you want to rearrange to make it the RHS with $k+1$. In order to do this, split and reindex and incorporate

$$\binom{n}{m}=\binom{n-1}{m}+\binom{n-1}{m-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks anon, I was able to work through it with this guidance.